# Create Linux crontab in PHP while using CPanel jailshell

Tags: php, linux, cron, cpanel, jail-shell

I'm attempting to manage crontabs in PHP without reinventing anything. Reading them works as expected. Writing crons in PHP does not. I have got the first code sample below to work with full shell access turned on. I'm wondering if there is a way get PHP to save a crontab with jailshell? I got it to work through jailshelled ssh via crontab -e and the default nano editor. Please and thank you.

```
passthru('echo "'.$cron.'" | crontab -', $response);
```

> '-' does not exist. usage: crontab file crontab [ -e | -l | -r ] -e
>   (edit user's crontab) -l (list user's crontab) -r (delete user's
>   crontab)

```
passthru('echo "'.$cron.'" | env EDITOR=echo crontab -e', $response);
```

> /var/tmp/14760.BIN_JAIL_SAFE_CRONTAB_PL__.RCL3wRzOq0IQGdOU.tmp
>   crontab: no changes

```
passthru('echo "'.$cron.'" | env EDITOR=cat crontab -e', $response);
```

> SHELL="/usr/local/cpanel/bin/jailshell" */5 * * * * /path/to/job -with
>   args */5 * * * * /path/to/job -with args crontab: no changes

Answer (score 0):

I think best solution if use php and bash

- crontab -u user -l > temp_file
- edit file (add, delete, modify lines with PHP code
- crontab -u user crontab.txt